# using javascript to hide input if user doesn't have javascript enabled - anyway to stop it flashing up quickly on page load?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a jquery range slider which, in case people have javascript disabled, needs to be two text inputs instead. So I use javascript to hide the inputs, so that if JavaScript is disabled then the inputs will be there for my non-JavaScript users.

So when the page loads the inputs appear just for a fraction of a second before the javascript kicks in and hides them. This is a little annoying but not a huge problem I suppose. Just wondering if anyone has a better way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: You should have this set with style="hidden".  Then you can use javascript to control it.

Comment: @David thanks for the reply but if I hide it with css then use javascript to show it then ppl without JS will never see it. They are the ones who need to see it :) Thanks anyway

Comment: Simplest is to use the script and noscript tags, but if you have a large site and many areas that need this then you could use javascript to write to a session or a cookie and then the server could read the cookie and determine what style would need to be applied. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, put the input fields inside a noscript tag (or alternative, non-hidden-by-css versions in noscript tag)

i.e.

```
<script>
// Output your base slider html via javascripthere
</script>
<noscript>
<!-- Your plain HTML fields here -->
</noscript>
```